# cannot convert from 'const char *' to 'LPCTSTR' in Debug

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

When I compile my code in Debug-Mode I get `error C2440 "cannot convert from 'const char *' to 'LPCTSTR'"`
When I compile the code in Release-Mode it compiles without error, I don't even get a warning.

the error occurs on line:

```
LPCTSTR lpFileName = strFilenameIni.c_str();
```

I use LPCTSTR because I use `GetPrivateProfileString` to read values from an ini file, and i need to convert the file location to LPCTSTR so GetPrivateProfileString accepts it.

I searched my compiler settings for something that can cause the deviation, but can't find anything.
I just can't get it to compile in debug mode.
I'm using Visual Studio 2005.

Any help is appreciated.

The code in question:

```
std::string strFilenameIni = "";  //filename of ini file

strFilenameIni = (char*)(void*)System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(textBox_ini_load->Text);

//init ini-parser strings
LPCTSTR lpFileName = strFilenameIni.c_str(); //<- this throws error in debug
LPCTSTR lpSection = "CHECKSUM";
LPCTSTR lpKey = "CRC";

TCHAR TCHAR_inBuf[11]; //buffer for CRC-number
GetPrivateProfileString(lpSection,lpKey,"",TCHAR_inBuf,11,lpFileName); //read CRC
unsigned long ulCRC_IN = strtoul(TCHAR_inBuf,NULL,16); //convert to unsigned long
```

Comment: Are you working with wide chars (16bit) actually? So you should probably use `std::wstring` instead of `std::string`. Also the initialization syntax you're trying to use doesn't work anyway. Check the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string) first please.

Comment: Probably you have different settings for `_UNICODE` in Debug and Release mode, which is a sign that someone has seriously messed up in the project properties.

Comment: Read the documentation.  An `LPCTSTR` is not a `const char*`.  It is a const pointer to a `TCHAR`.  If you really want your code to compile and still use STL containers, use a `std::vector<TCHAR>` instead of `std::string`.

Comment: Thanks @MatteoItalia. In Debug-Mode the Character Set was changed, TCHAR and CString are defined differently in Unicode and MBCS. Learned that just now ;)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: probably the best thing would be an `std::basic_string<TCHAR>`, that I've seen `typedef`ed in many projects as `tstring`.

Comment: @MatteoItalia - Yes, you're right.  The `basic_string<TCHAR>` would be a better choice.

Comment: Even better, screw the ANSI half and always pass in wide strings. Why create another build for yourself just to limit the number of characters you can use unless you're supporting really old versions of Windows?

Comment: You are using a deprecated windows API call in a C++/CLI WinForms app? Also, use `marshal_as` to get to/from `String^` and C++ "native" strings.

Answer (score 1):

Seems some problems are remaining after changing Character Set as commented.
Anyway you should use one of the following API set all the way; not mix them up.

For single byte character:

```
char,    LPCSTR,  std::string,  GetPrivateProfileStringA, strtoul,  "literal"
```

For wide(2 bytes) charater:

```
wchar_t, LPCWSTR, std::wstring, GetPrivateProfileStringW, wcstoul,  L"literal"
```

For the case depending on `_UNICODE`:

```
TCHAR,   LPCTSTR, **,           GetPrivateProfileString,  _tcstoul, _T("literal")
```

** there's no predefined way by standard, you'd better use like:

```
typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring;
```